# iPhone Core Data error?

Tags: iphone, sqlite, core-data

What does this mean?

```
Detected an attempt to call a symbol in system libraries that is not present on the iPhone:
_Unwind_Resume called from function -[NSSQLCore performChanges] in image CoreData.
```

Comment: _Unwind_Resume is used by pthread locking, generally you see an error like this when you tweak the bits of a pthread lock in such a way that it cannot be unlocked (i.e. an owning thread is destroyed without releasing the lock).  CoreData is known to not be threadsafe, are you using threads in your app anywhere, and if so can you post that code so we can take a look?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I noticed I had a corruption in the sqlite file that I use to seed the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`. In the `Z_PRIMARYKEY` table of this sqlite file, some of the `Z_MAX` fields were set to 0 but should've been 1. When I fixed this, it got rid of the error above.

Comment: How did you set the Z_MAX? I have that problem too, but it's in the database of the customers phone. I can change my database forward going, but how do I update their database?